# Primality test for specific class of $3\cdot 2^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, primality-test

I am interested in approaches which can be used to prove ( disprove ) conjecture given below .

Let's define number $N$ as : $N=3\cdot 2^n+1$ such that $n \equiv 2,6,8,10 \pmod{12}$ or $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ .

Let's define starting seed $S$ as :

$S =
\begin{cases}
 50542, & \text{if } n\equiv 8 \pmod {12} \\
 32672, & \text{if } n\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
 1692, & \text{if } n\equiv 2 \pmod {12} \\
 21868, & \text{if }n\equiv 6,10 \pmod {12}
\end{cases}$

Let's define sequence $S_i$ as :

$S_i=S^2_{i-1}-2~$ with $~S_0=S$

> **Conjecture :**
>
> $N ; (n > 2)~$ is a prime iff $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod N$

I have checked this claim for all exponents under $100000$ from [this list](https://oeis.org/A002253) .

Comment: The best approach for disproving such a conjecture would be looking for a counterexample by testing composite numbers as well. The best approach for understanding the problem would be to familiarize yourself with the standard primality tests based on the factorizations of n+1 and n-1. But perhaps this is not an option as this would keep you from posting this question over and over again.